# How retain certain index for more time than the other?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm on Elasticsearch 6.4, I have 4 indexes out of which for 2 I need to set the retention period to be 60 days, how do I set that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add and ILM with a delete phase on those 2 and maybe a different one other (or not at all on others)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html